# Pyinstaller - Flask template not found “bootstrap/base.html”

Tags: pyinstaller, flask-bootstrap

I am trying to make a distributable flask application. Everything works fine when running locally.

When an executable is generated with `pyinstaller` it gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app

  File "site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
  File "site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
  File "site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
  File "site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
  File "site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
  File "app.py", line 39, in index
  File "site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 140, in render_template
  File "site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 120, in _render
  jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: bootstrap/base.html
```

## Some friends say：

create a new python file named 'hook-flask_bootstrap.py', inside of this paste the following:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files
datas = collect_data_files('flask_bootstrap')
```

Now when you run `pyinstaller` provide the path to this `'hook-flask_bootstrap.py'` file:

I use command line:

```
**pyinstaller -D --i icon\crawler_spider72.ico --additional-hooks-dir hook-flask_bootstrap.py run.py**
```

**I searched for some answers, but after using, there was no action collected. Don't know where the mistake is. Ask the knowledgeable person for advice. Thank you**

Comment: This question would be easier to answer with an example app. Try to reproduce the issue on the most minimal code possible in a new flask application. Publish the minimal sample project to a public source code repo like github. Include detailed steps for reproducing the error. Try out a pyinstaller flask tutorial that is known to work correctly, then look for differences between that and your sample.

Comment: First of all, thank you for answering my questions. Later, I found a similar situation in pyinstaller Q & A. Follow the prompts below to solve the problem. Thank you again.

Hooks are placed in ./PyInstaller/hooks/
PyInstaller/utils/hooks is only for helper functions
As an example you could use any file from PyInstaller/hooks that contains collect_data_files.
It looks like you need hook like hook-flask_bootstrap.py:
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files
datas = collect_data_files('flask_bootstrap')